# Sass::Engine.new causes Sass::SyntaxError on @import

Tags: ruby, sass

I'm writing my own static site generator in ruby and I'm in the process of adding Sass compiler to my code.

```
def compile_sass
  # system 'sass _sass/styles.scss styles.css'
  options = {
    syntax: :scss,
    style: :compressed
  }
  render = Sass::Engine.new(File.read('_sass/styles.scss'), options).render
  File.write('style.css', render)
end
```

But problem occurs when the styles.scss file has @import in it. Causing

```
(sass):1: File to import not found or unreadable: variables. (Sass::SyntaxError)
```

Both SCSS files are located in *_sass* folder, main script in root, and compile_sass is located in _generator. But when I uncomment the system call and comment the rest, everything works as expected.

**styles.scss**

```
@import 'variables';

html {
  background-color: red;
}
```

**_variables.scss**

```
body {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

I tried almost everything, checked [how to import stuff](http://sass-lang.com/guide), [looked at the documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html), but I can't find anything that would helped me find and define the problem.

Comment: Why do you expect [`@import`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import) to prepend _underscore_ to the imported file name?

Comment: @mudasobwa You don't need underscore to import the stylesheet..

Comment: @mudasobwa their documentation [says I should put it in there](http://sass-lang.com/guide) (but it doesn't work with or without the underscore).

Comment: maybe the working directory is changed at runtime ,try giving a absolute path to `@import`

Comment: @maxpleaner I tried all the possible variations with or without .scss, with or without underscore with no success

Comment: I mean with the absolute path too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had to load all `_sass/*.scss` files into **Sass::Engine** like this:

```
Sass::Engine::DEFAULT_OPTIONS[:load_paths].tap do |load_paths|
  load_paths << '_sass'
end
```